# Disconnected vertical lines with Latex table using booktabs package

Tags: latex

I want the vertical lines in my table disconnected like in the example below.

[image]

My attempt is getting me vertical lines like in the second table shown below, how can I reproduce the lines like in the example?

[image]

This is my code to generate my table

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{arydshln}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
\begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
\toprule
classes  & abs\_rel & a1    & a2    & a3    \\ \midrule
Road    & 0.138               & 0.851          & 0.917          & 0.946 \\ %\hline
Vehicle & 0.135               & 0.855          & 0.920          & 0.948 \\ %\hline
Lane    & 0.135               & 0.855          & 0.920          & 0.947 \\ %\hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, that you're interested in the disconnected vertical lines?

Comment: Yes, i'm interested in the disconnected vertical lines...

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your question, trying to make it more concise. You're saying, you're using the booktabs package, please expand your code to be a fully working example we can just copy into our local environment to test things. This includes all relevant packages and things like /begin and /end document. 
This will make the question easier to understand and answer.

Comment: @yelin2 Are you sure you want to replicate a table in which someone made an error and used the booktabs package incorrectly?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I haven't been familiar with the booktabs package for a long time yet, so there is still a lot I don't know. If I am misusing the booktabs package, could you tell me which part I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: The person who produced the table with the vertical gaps misused booktabs. I wouldn't recommend to replicate this table. It would look very amateurish if you did this, like you don't know now your way around latex. Make a nice looking table instead.

Comment: If I see the table in your first image, I immediately think "somebody couldn't be bothered to read the booktabs documentation", even before actually looking at the content of your table. Do you want to provoke this reaction from your readers or do you want them to focus on what you are trying to tell them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can replicate the incorrect usage of booktabs with vertical lines if you refrain form loading the `arydshln` package. This package would fix some of the incompatibilities of booktabs with vertical lines.

However please consider carefully if you really want your table to look like you made an error in coding it. It will look as if you don't know your latex.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%\usepackage{arydshln}


\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{center}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
\begin{tabular}{c|cccc}
\toprule
classes  & abs\_rel & a1    & a2    & a3    \\ \midrule
Road    & 0.138               & 0.851          & 0.917          & 0.946 \\ %\hline
Vehicle & 0.135               & 0.855          & 0.920          & 0.948 \\ %\hline
Lane    & 0.135               & 0.855          & 0.920          & 0.947 \\ %\hline
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem by not loading the arydshln package. Then, is it common not to use vertical lines when using the booktabs package?

Comment: @yelin2 Yes! If you want your table to look professional, I would use `\begin{tabular}{@{}lcccc@{}}`. This will remove the vertical lines and a left aligned first column will look much more calm as the ragged look of a centred column.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I won't use booktabs package to draw vertical lines. I will try to use `{@{}lcccc@{}}` as you suggested!

Comment: @yelin2 You're welcome! Your table will look so much better without the vertical line!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an answer just for completeness. If your goal is to have the same gaps across the table, stick to `booktabs`.

However, custom gaps can be created without loading `booktabs` as long as they are added before `tabular` starts creating a new row. Essentially gaps become a part of a rule, not a part of rows/cells. It is achieved by a TeX primitive `\noalign{}`; it can only be used between rows! For instance, one can place the following line between rows

```
% ...
\hline \noalign{\vskip 3pt}
% ...
```

and get the 3pt skip below the `\hline` which breaks the vertical bar. Since you have added `makecell` package, `\Xhline{<<rule size>>}` is also available. Combined with `\noalign{\vskip <<size>>}` and you can have custom gaps with custom rules.

Here's the example where I made a convenient macros: `\Gap` and parametrised `\XGap{<<size>>`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\XGap{m}{\noalign{\vskip #1}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\Gap{}{\XGap{3pt}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
    \begin{tabular}{c | *4{c}}
      \Xhline{0.8pt} \XGap{1pt}
      classes & abs\_rel & a1    & a2    & a3    \\
      \Gap \hline \Gap
      Road    & 0.138    & 0.851 & 0.917 & 0.946 \\
      Vehicle & 0.135    & 0.855 & 0.920 & 0.948 \\
      Lane    & 0.135    & 0.855 & 0.920 & 0.947 \\
      \XGap{1pt} \Xhline{0.8pt}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The macros can be stack, repeated after each row and used with negative skips to achieve some special effects. For instance, consider this table

```latex
\begin{table}[h]
  \begin{center}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
    \begin{tabular}{c | *4{c}}
      \Xhline{0.8pt} \XGap{1pt}
      classes & abs\_rel & a1    & a2    & a3    \\\Gap
      \hline \Gap
      Road    & 0.138    & 0.851 & 0.917 & 0.946 \\\Gap
      Vehicle & 0.135    & 0.855 & 0.920 & 0.948 \\\Gap
      Lane    & 0.135    & 0.855 & 0.920 & 0.947 \\\Gap\XGap{-2pt}
      \Xhline{0.8pt}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
```

[image]